# is it possible to access another PC by IP Address in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, ios4, remote-access

In my apps I want to parse XML from a certain IP address like 192.168.1.48 which is in a local network.Is it possible to  access another PC by IP address & parse XML from that PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to my local file through NSURL by using:  `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://192.168.1.48/localhost/Volumes/foyzulkarim/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];`

but, to do this you have to first connect with that PC manually.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to setup a web server on the PC and grab the XML over HTTP. If you do it in fancy ways it could be called a web service.

Comment: I don't want to be any protocol specific like http or ftp. I just want simply access to certain IP and parse XML

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Wyatt has mentioned, you can set up a Wi-fi router in your local network and let your device connect to the network through it. That way it would be on your local network.